# What's the best way to Hide/Show labels in vb.net 2005?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have this labels in my project

```
num1.Hide()
num2.Hide()
num3.Hide()
.
.
.
num20.Hide()
```

What's the best way to hide/show them? I'm thinking of loop but i can't make it work.

Comment: I assume this is winforms not WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You should put all all your labels in a list, Then to hide or show your elements, just iterate the list in a function to do your action on all elements.

Comment: How will i do that? I'm kinda new in vb.net. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*One* solution:

Create an array of labels at runtime then you can loop through them to make them invisible:

```
'define the array
Dim labelArray(5) As Label

Private Sub createLabels

    'add them to the form
    For i As Integer = 0 To labelArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        initLabel(i, New Point(i * 30, i * 30), i.ToString)
    Next

    'now hide them
    For i As Integer = 0 To labelArray.GetUpperBound(0)
        labelArray(i).Visible = False
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub initLabel(ByVal index As Integer, location As System.Drawing.Point, caption As String)
    labelArray(index) = New Label
    With labelArray(index)
        'set some default properties
        .Name = "LabelArray" + index.ToString
        .Width = 300
        .Height = 100
        .Location = location
        .Text = caption
    End With
    Me.Controls.Add(labelArray(index))
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way i can control using a normal loop like `num+i.Hide()`?

Comment: what kind of labels are you trying to .hide(), i am pretty sure you need to set their visibility = false